# How to use TypedValue class

Tags: android

I'm a newbie in Android Programming.
Could everyone answer for me the below questions about `TypedValue` class.

1. What is it? Although i have read the definition but it's hard to
   understand
2. what case is it used?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a BIG questions, hard to say in word of lines, but word of pages. All in all, It is a helper to convert Units.

Answer (score 0):

**TypedValue class** holds raw representations of typed data like - floats, dimensions, etc. which are loaded from compiled Android XML resources.

**TypedValue class** is a used as an intermediary or as a medium between  resources framework and places where app developers need to stored values in resources.

For example you want to resolve dimension, so you can use TypedValue class as below:-

```
protected void setTextSize(float size) {
    mTextSizePx = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
            size, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(mTextSizePx);
    mLayout.reflowLines();
    invalidate();
    requestLayout();
}
```

For more information and understanding you can follow official link - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html